# Login with cookies through Http Client

Tags: java, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x

i already made this code

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/Account/Login");

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String str ="";
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(""+str);
    }
        entity.consumeContent();
    }
    System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
    List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("None");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
        }
    }

    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/Account/Login");

    List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", "e"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "password"));

    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

    response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
    entity = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println("Double check we've got right page " + EntityUtils.toString(entity));

    System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
    if (entity != null) {
        entity.consumeContent();
    }

    System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
    cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("None");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("2nd- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
```

is this already right??
and how to get to another url???
lets say after from login page,, i want to go to localhost:80/test page.
help me to resolve this.. i'm new to this http client.

this is the post request:

```
    POST http://localhost:8080/netbank/j_spring_security_check?spring-security-redirect=/login/ajaxSuccess HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101  Firefox/23.0
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/netbank/bank/login
    Content-Length: 176
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=0A219D4AE7171E3C495443C1063B49F1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Pragma: no-cache
    Cache-Control: no-cache

    j_username=(Username)&j_password=(password)

    **POST SERVER RESPONSE**

    HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=E2152CA4CE8B0BB8375F216A30E32EC0; Path=/netbank
    Location: http://localhost:8080/netbank/login/ajaxSuccess
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2013 02:51:54 GMT
```

this is the get request:

```
    GET http://localhost:8080/netbank/login/ajaxSuccess HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/netbank/bank/login
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=E2152CA4CE8B0BB8375F216A30E32EC0
    Connection: keep-alive
    Pragma: no-cache
    Cache-Control: no-cache

    **GET SERVER RESPONSE** 

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2013 02:51:54 GMT

    35
    {"success":true,"change":false,"username":(Username)}
    0
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what you want your program to do and what is not working in the current version.

Comment: @iX3 from this code,, i can get the cookie, and the status for the webpage is 200(OK).

from that, i want to go to another page, using the given cookies,, 
until now,, that is what not working..
everytime i httpGet another webpage within the localhost:80. its only show the html code of login page,, which means, its not logged in yet,,

Comment: BTW, you should be careful to remove sensitive information from any kind of capture like this. I assume that this is all from a test system, so it doesn't matter, but it's usually a good idea to scrub out things like usernames and passwords by replacing them with something like (the username) and (correct password)

Comment: @iX3 yeah,, its test system,, but thanks for reminding me,,

Comment: No, sorry, an HTTP response will not start with GET, POST, etc. it typically looks something like this: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` where 1.1 is the protocol version, 200 is the status code, and "OK" is the reason phrase. Fiddler shows this in the lower pane of the inspector (click "Raw" view). See http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/fiddler-in-action/part-1 for more details.

Comment: Also, here's [a picture](http://blogs.infragistics.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/anton_5F00_staykov.FiddlerIntro/fiddler_5F00_03_5F00_inspectors.png); the HTTP response is represented in the lower-right corner.

Comment: @iX3 okay,, already added the server response,, thanks for your patience in guiding me through this. :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the HTTP requests & responses. That is very helpful. Judging from that information it appears that the login was successful. As you can see, the first response includes a `Set-Cookie` header with JSESSIONID=E215...2EC0", and the second requests includes a `Cookie` header with that exact same value. The body of the second response further confirms this as it says "...success:true...". However, note that the cookie only applies to path `/netbank` so it won't be usable for the path `/test`-- you can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path).

Comment: @iX3 thanks,, i already read it,, so,, i have to set a new cookie to get to /test path?.. how to get that cookie?? hmm

Comment: If a cookie set by the server restricts its path to `/netbank` then the client is never supposed to send it for other requests. This is part of [RFC2109](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2109#section-4.3.4). The client will never send that cookie in a request for any path beginning with `/test`. I suggest using Fiddler to monitor the behavior of a "normal" web browser like Chrome or Firefox to see what is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you do `response = httpclient.execute(httpget);` and `response = httpclient.execute(httpost);` you need to include the
`HttpContext` as an argument so that the cookies are sent.
See [HttpClient.execute(HttpUriRequest request, HttpContext context)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext%29).

BTW, it would also be helpful if you listed the output of your program and what you want it to be instead.

Also, I would recommend using some kind of HTTP traffic inspection tool so you can see exactly what is being sent in each request and response. For example, if you're using regular (not encrypted) HTTP then you can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). There are also some great debugging tools that work by acting as an HTTP(S) proxy, such as [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).

Comment: the output only shows the login page html,, which i suppose its not using the cookie to the page i want to., after i add context to execute method,, it still giving the same output..

Comment: Please look at the actual network traffic using one of the tools I suggested. [e.g. Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureFiddler) You can paste the HTTP request and response data into your question.

Comment: i dont know if this is the right data you thought of..

i paste it into my question

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for, except that this does not show the server's responses, it just shows the two requests. Please post the responses as well. One thing I do notice though is that the `JSESSIONID` value in the cookie is changing between the `GET` and the `POST`.

Comment: hmm,, i dont know if thats what you mean with server response,, fiddler only gave me that information after logging in.,,